# what does the code snippet Class Abc <R extends XYZ> extends DAO stands for?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, dao

I have code snippet which is as follows:

```
public class Abc <R extends XYZ> extends DAO{
.
.
.
}
```

Can someone explain this snippet?
Thanks In advance.

Comment: What part don't you understand, I assume your aware DAO refers to Data Access Objects?

Comment: I know that Abc extends DAO that means it has the properties of its parents. And the generic class has inherited the properties of XYZ. But what I didn't get is that what is the use of writing this and what will be the effect of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a declaration of a class `Abc` that [extends](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_inheritance) a class `DAO` ([data access object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object)). The generics part `<R extends XYZ>` says that it can be used to insert, update and/or delete objects `R` that extend the class `XYZ` (most probably a [data transfer object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object)). Now, there's no declaration of the `R` class. It's just a placeholder to whatever class extending `XYZ`.

Comment: Can you just elaborate this a bit more. If possible.

Comment: Take a look at the blog post "Generic DAO example" (http://www.bejug.org/confluenceBeJUG/display/BeJUG/Generic+DAO+example) for a detailed info and examples. Following the links in the answer can lead to in depth explanations of terms.

Answer (score 1):

Abc is a subclass of DAO and also includes a generic R which is a subclass of type XYZ

Comment: Since I am new to java could you use a bit more lengthy expalanition.

Answer (score 1):

Your class `Abc` is a subclass of class type `DAO`. This means that the following will compile:

```
DAO abc = new Abc();
```

Secondly, your `Abc` class has defined a generic type, `R`. This type must be a subclass of `XYZ`. This means that for any class that can be referred to as `XYZ`, can be used to add genericity to this class `Abc`.

```
public class ARGH extends XYZ { }

Abc<ARGH> abc = new Abc<ARGH>();
```

This means that for any type `R` inside `Abc`, it will now be of type `ARGH`.

```
public class Abc <R extends XYZ> extends DAO {
    R element;

    public Abc(R element) {
       this.element = element;
    }
}
```